# In flex, how to remove empty lines in text area?

Tags: regex, apache-flex, textarea

In flex, how to remove empty lines in text area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean unwanted blank lines created by gratuitous carriage returns, here's one way. I made it verbose for clarity, but you could reduce it to a single line if  you wanted.

```
private function stripLinesFromTextArea (textArea:TextArea) : void {
  var txt:String = textArea.text;
  var re:RegExp = /\n+/g;
  txt = txt.replace(re,"\n");
  textArea.text = txt;
}
```